# exporting mercurial patch against an old revision

Tags: mercurial

I am very new to software development, so this is no doubt a very basic question. I got a mercurial repo of an open-source project. I copied it and worked a bit. Commited. Worked more, then did second commit. So my tree looks like 1(from net) -> 2 (mine) -> 3 (mine) (changed numbers of course).

Now I want a patch to send to the rest of the world. However, I have two patches. How can I make it one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
hg export -a -o FILENAME x:y
```

Where x is the first revision and y is the last. All it really does is concatenate diffs of each revision in the range into the same file.

Run `hg help export` for more information.